# Variadic templates and constraints

Tags: c++, constraints, c++20, variadic-templates

I have a variadic template function that takes as parameters file name, delimiter, and non-specified number of containers as columns. This function then parses to file all values in containers that represent columns and between all values put delimiter.

```
bool parseToFile (const std::string& file, const char delimiter, auto&... columns)
{
    bool done {false};
    std::ofstream out;
    out.open (file, std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc);
    if (!out)
    {
        done = false;
        std::cout << "SaveFile: Cannot open file: " << file << "!" ;
        std::cout << std::strerror (errno) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::size_t maxContainerSize {0};
        auto maxSize = [&maxContainerSize] (std::size_t containerSize)
        {
            maxContainerSize = std::max (maxContainerSize, containerSize);
        };
        (maxSize (columns.size()), ...);
        std::size_t i {0};
        auto implementation = [&i, delimiter, &out] (auto & cont, std::size_t s)
        {
            if (i < cont.size())
                out << cont[i];

            out << delimiter;
        };
        for (; i < maxContainerSize; ++i)
        {
            (implementation (columns, columns.size()), ...);
            out << "\n";
        }
        out << std::flush;
        done = true;
    return done;
}
```

This works as intended correctly.

But this template has several constraints releating to what can be parameter pack "columns"

- it should be a container
- any container should overload operator [] to get access to objects (eg. std::vector, std::deque)
- any object in the container should have operator << to be able to work with iostream

How should I change my code to implement this constraint?

I have tried this:

```
template <template <typename, typename> class Container,
          typename Value,
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<Value>>
concept containerHasPrintable = requires (std::ostream& out, Container<Value,Allocator>& data)
{
    out << data[0];
};

// and definition:
bool parseToFile (const std::string& file, const char delimiter, containerHasPrintable&... columns);
```

But this does not work. GCC 13.1

```
main.cpp|80|error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be at least 2)| "80 - function"
main.cpp|40|note: provided for 'template<template<class, class> class Container, class Value, class Allocator> concept containerHasPrintable'| "40 - concept"
main.cpp|80|error: expansion pattern 'int&' contains no parameter packs|
```

How can I constrain the template?

Comment: You might simply max computation to: `const std::size_t maxContainerSize = std::max({containers.size()...});`.

Comment: `out << data[0];` will make it reject containers without `operator[]`, like `std::list<int>`, for no good reason. `out << *std::begin(data);` would be a better test. Also, make  `data`  into a `const&` , just in case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo although the implementation would have to change to e.g. [this](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c5feb3a6ae4ccc45)

Comment: @Caleth This is really better, but I do not know if it is even possible to make an opposite function to load data from file to containers.

Comment: @TomášNadrchal you can construct a `std::inserter` for each container, and `in >> *it`, where the only worry is dealing with missing values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```cpp
template <template <typename, typename> class Container,
          typename Value,
          typename Allocator = std::allocator<Value>>
concept containerHasPrintable = /* ... */;
```

Is a concept that is constraining *three* things: a template and two types. But that's not actually what you want - you want a concept that is constraining *one* thing: a type.

So what you want to write is just that:

```cpp
template <typename Container>
concept PrintableContainer = requires (std::ostream& out, Container& data)
{
    out << data[0];
};
```

Note that none of the other stuff in your concept is actually relevant - you don't need the container to specifically look like `C<V, A>` anyway - and this just arbitrarily rejects some other types that would otherwise work (like, say, `std::string`).

Comment: `data.size()` should also be required, BTW.

Answer (score 1):

I'd break it down into a few sub-concepts.

This has a few advantages.  First, the subsuming rules like it when you do this.  Second, you get better error messages -- being told which concepts fail by name.  Third, it is somewhat better in self documentation.

```
template<class Container>
concept IndexedContainer = requires(Container const& data) {
  data[0];
  std::size(data);
};
template<class T>
concept CanStreamOut = requires(T t, std::ostream& os) {
  os << t;
};
template<class C>
concept ElementCanStreamOut = requires(C const& c) {
  { c[0] } -> CanStreamOut;
};
template<class C>
concept PrintableRange = IndexedContainer<C> && ElementCanStreamOut<C>;
```

The `const&` portion helps block [`std::map` from passing these tests](https://godbolt.org/z/7Yorn3v15).

Comment: why do you need to forbid `std::map`?

Comment: @caleth because accessing it from 0 to size-1 is nonsense